# Echo не выводит переводы строк

Tags: php

В базе записано 1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5

echo должно выводить:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Выводит:

```
12345
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Чтобы `echo` начал выводить по строчкам, для этого нужно устанавливать заголовок `text/plain`, а так-как вы, работаете с `html`, то `\n` работать не будет..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo nl2br('1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5');//поправил опечатку с nl
```

Или

```
echo '<pre>1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5</pre>';
```

В зависимости от задачи